# Question on svylogrank() in survival package

Tags: r, survival, survey, logrank-test

I am running a survival model with sampling weights and was hoping to get the weighted logrank test results. When I use the `svylogrank()` function from the survey package, the results were puzzling. If I run the default svylogrank test, the returned chisq value seemed way too high, and when I run the function with the method set to "score", the results were much more reasonable and as expected. Based on my understanding of the parameter `method`, it should only matter for performance and should not affect the results, and I believe my model matrix is also relatively small.

Could someone help advise on this issue?

```
D = data.table(unique_id = 1:135,
               weights = rep(1,135),
               event_time = c(0.53512437, 1.35655869, 2.00414189, 2.37276648, 3.20343526, 0.96618494, 2.57894309, 0.94575080, 1.25347833, 1.44416450, 5.04038200, 7.80587169 ,
                        6.53631154, 6.31914568, 7.00146597, 9.67616088, 7.94212358, 9.70693890, 10.67575835, 10.06764688, 12.29175616, 13.60092871, 13.12508566, 14.66417522,
                        15.35250691, 0.93368707, 0.19087611, 3.15533767, 4.40821633, 17.54334957, 17.95177642, 15.50903946, 16.48376185, 20.87956697, 21.24571398, 22.34297263,
                        23.36042629, 21.01760215, 23.84785038, 26.06105822, 4.16866350, 1.96922485, 0.66199008, 6.76987830, 1.55617685, 0.19095871, 3.13291784, 5.43159409,
                        9.55805671, 4.31437322, 0.78259860, 5.26415156, 3.45095686, 1.69128712, 8.41942426, 3.33748695, 6.08516173, 2.72897404, 0.22789783, 0.86348009,
                        2.35707587, 2.97477615, 12.33273800, 0.58532123, 0.14586238, 10.67948547, 4.07655972, 3.94405136, 0.37226898, 1.42558725, 1.47680658, 4.22506540,
                        1.56703478, 8.37484756, 12.54015087, 1.80994787, 3.66453633, 1.02834532, 1.99065652, 1.23577436, 16.21981618, 14.35039798, 4.15321606, 2.79740679,
                        0.35538726, 7.46823358, 1.66329088, 7.46525382, 2.62734831, 3.19057957, 0.33317193, 0.09122886, 9.14616245, 2.48542578, 2.37569263, 5.48499630,
                        2.22749399, 2.64816296, 0.97101545, 1.42468625, 1.27668904, 0.03692447, 1.98783210, 5.47692729, 3.88316178, 0.32921277, 1.77225345, 9.33268901,
                        2.44517775, 1.49813702, 2.56059172, 3.43194832, 1.22955630, 3.56263947, 9.07060099, 3.58312362, 2.22755370, 4.24783776, 3.46364804, 1.61671354,
                        11.10973565, 7.18764270, 1.80400046, 6.39833474, 6.72825192, 6.46063344, 5.76855531, 5.27157807, 4.66154734, 3.50019718, 2.27156678, 3.28531594,
                        2.35699896, 2.94956000, 8.85381736),
               event_flag = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
                              1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                              1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
               group = c(rep("group1", 40), rep("group2", 95)))

svykm_formula = "Surv(event_time, event_flag) ~ group" %>% as.formula
svy_design = svydesign( ids = D[ , unique_id ], weights = D[ , weights], data = D )

svylogrank(formula = svykm_formula, design = svy_design)
svylogrank(formula = svykm_formula, design = svy_design, method = "score")
```

Results:

````
> svylogrank(formula = svykm_formula, design = svy_design)
[[1]]
         score                               
[1,] -21.31458 3.99272 -5.338361 9.379041e-08

[[2]]
       chisq            p 
2.849810e+01 9.379041e-08 

attr(,"class")
[1] "svylogrank"
> svylogrank(formula = svykm_formula, design = svy_design, method = "score")
z.groupgroup2         Chisq             p 
   1.85490656    3.44067835    0.06360957 
attr(,"class")
[1] "svylogrank"
```
````